# Como llamar una funcion c# desde un onchange en asp.net core

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, funciones, asp.net-core

Tengo estos dos select los cuales los cargo en el c# desde el metodo OnGet(), despues quiero que cuando el usuario cambie de opcion en el select almacen que se ejecute la funcion CargarUsuarios(con el valor del almacen) la cual carga usuarios de ese almacen en el select usuarios. Necesito una explicacion de como puedo llamar la funcion desde el metodo onchange()

```
            <select asp-for="AlmacenUsuario" id="almacen">
                <option value="">Seleccione un almacén</option>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Almacenes)
                {
                    <option value="@item.Almacen">@item.Descripcion</option>
                }
            </select>
            <select asp-for="NombreUsuario" id="usuario">
                <option value="">Seleccione un usuario</option>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Usuarios)
                {
                    <option value="@item.Usuario">@item.Nombre</option>
                }
            </select>


public void CargarUsuarios()
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();

            string cnString = config.GetConnectionString("INFORMATICA");

            if (cnString == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("La cadena de conexión es incorrecta, revísela");
            }

            Usuarios = new List<UsuarioItem>();
            string sqlQuery = "SELECT VUsuarios.Usu_cod AS usuario, VUsuarios.usu_descripcion AS nombre" +
                              " FROM VUsuarios" +
                              " WHERE VUsuarios.Usu_fecha_baja IS NULL" +
                              " AND VUsuarios.Usu_Pertenece_Almacen = " + Utilidades.FormatoTextoSQL(AlmacenUsuario) +
                              " ORDER BY nombre";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cnString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            string usuario = reader.GetString(0);
                            string nombre = reader.GetString(1);
                            Usuarios.Add(new UsuarioItem { Usuario = usuario, Nombre = nombre });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```